# Mips - Is there any way to get the space in an array into a variable?

Tags: mips

Is there any way to get the number of bytes in an array?

```
     .data
array: .space 40
...
some other code
```

Is there anyway to put the number 40 into a register to use it as a variable?

Comment: Nope. You have to write it out wherever you want it.

Comment: Alright, thats what I planned on doing if there was no other way of getting it.

Comment: did I misunderstand your question or are you looking for li $t0, 40?

Comment: No, that's pretty much what I was looking for, I just wasn't being smart about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
.data 
array: space 40
array_end: 
...

.text
...
la $t0, array
la $t1, array_end
sub $t2, $t1, $t0   # $t2 should contain 40
...
```

The above code should leave the size of `array` in `$t2`

Comment: Good call. All though not really something I would recommend over `li $t0 40`.